# Nginxで「開発中の」Railsアプリに対するパスベースのリバースプロキシ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

外部に対してポートが80しか開いていない環境を開発者複数で共有するため、パスベースのリバースプロキシをしようと思っています。開発環境なのでサーバーは WEBrick です。

`http://server/devel1` に接続すると localhost:3000 に、
`http://server/devel2` に接続すると localhost:3001 に、

飛ぶように設定したいのです。

Twitterで聞いたところ @matsuu さんに

https://gist.github.com/matsuu/c4b5532075c95401fb9e

の設定でいけるのでは、と教えていただいたきました。
試したところ、確かに `http://server/devel1` にアクセスすると WEBrick で上げたRailsアプリには接続できますが、アプリケーションがちゃんと動いていません。
Nginxのエラーログを見ると、

```
2015/03/24 23:26:35 [error] 7627#0: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/rails/info/properties" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 126.185.134.71, server: localhost, request: "GET /rails/info/properties HTTP/1.1", host: "119.81.181.117", referrer: "http://119.81.181.117/foo/"
```

のようなエラーが出ていて、Railsアプリ内のリクエストがROOTを向いてしまっているのが原因のようなのです。
アプリ側になにか設定が必要なのかなと思うのですが、この環境で動かすだけのためにあまり手を入れたくないというところがあります。
どのようにするのが適切でしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

私ならそのような状況ならvirtualhostで対応しますが、パスベースでリバースプロクシを利用する場合は[この質問](https://serverfault.com/q/351701)が参考になるかと思います。

```
location /foo {
    rewrite           ^/foo$ https://example.net/foo/ permanent;
    rewrite           ^/foo/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass        http://localhost:9000;
}
```

ただし、パスベースだとアプリ内で絶対パスを使うと(工夫すれば問題ないけれど)面倒なのでお勧めできないかと。

Comment: リンク先の質問も参照してみました。なるほど……。結局アプリ側の問題を解消するには時間が足りなかったので、アドバイスの通りvirtualhostで対応することとしました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

railsのバージョンにもよりますが、
ActionController::AbstractRequest.relative_url_root = '/foo'
もしくは
ActionController::Base.relative_url_root = '/foo'
のような設定を入れるとどうでしょうか。

Comment: やはりRails側に設定がいるのですね。今回はRails3なので：

http://quickhack.net/nom/blog/2012-09-19-rails-with-relative-url-root.html

ココらへんを参考にしてみて、(1) config.ru の編集、(2)実行時に環境変数 RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT を指定、の二点をやってみたのですが、正しくassetsが読めないという現象に陥ったので諦めました。次回機会があれば参考にしてみます。